# Securing a JWT token

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, jwt

In general, JWT has an encoded message with a signature. The signature uses for checking the genuinity of the data. My question is, this signature is for assuring the client about the server, but how server can trust the client? In other words, if a client sends a JWT to the server, how the server can be sure this is the right/authenticated client?

My second question is about JWT's lifetime. I know there is a claim (exp) which can be set to indicate JWT's expiry. But what if the client changes that claim? Should I keep expiry date on the server to make sure the JWT is still valid? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) says: To validate the session stored in the token is not revoked, token assertions must be checked against a data store. This renders the tokens no longer stateless, undermining the primary advantage of JWTs.

Comment: Hopefully the secret key to create the JWT signature is only known to server, which would prevent client from creating a fake JWT that the server would accept (assuming you don't have implementation problems).

Comment: @TheGreatContini, client should know about the secret, to verify it is really from the server.

Comment: that's not a good design.  If you use public key crypto (ECC or RSA), client does not need to know the secret and can do the verification with the public key only.

Answer (score 1):

Given a JWT, the server knows that the client is legitimate by verifying that the HMAC of the header and payload is equal to the signature. The server has a secret key that it uses when computing the HMAC, so if someone wanted to create a fake JWT with a proper signature, they would need to have access to this key.

Your second question shares the same idea as the first. If a client wanted to change the expiration of their JWT, they would have to recompute the signature, and to do this successfully, they'd have to know the secret key.

The point of using JWTs is not to store data like the expiration date on the server, all of this data lives inside the token itself, and the integrity of this data is protected by the secret key used to compute the signature.

Comment: Thank's for your comment. I have a doubt here, JWT generates by the OAuth server, right? And the secret should be shared with the client, so it can verify the genuinity of the token.
This way, the client can produce the JWT, and extend (an already expired) token.
Is there anything I missed?

Comment: @Amir The secret key should only be known to the server! Neither the OAuth provider nor the client should have access to the secret key. Usually this is how it works: the server asks the OAuth provider for an OAuth code, converts this into a JWT token, and gives the JWT to the client. From then on, the client will pass the JWT to the server whenever it makes a request.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought it is between the server and the client.

Answer (score 0):

JSON web token (JWT) can come in two flavours. Typical, the most widely used form is to use JWT with a JSON web signature (JWS). In security world, this provide ***integrity***. Other form is JWT with JSON web encryption (JWE). This form provides both ***integrity*** and ***confidentiality***.

So if you have a specific requirement to identify that you get a valid, condifential JWT, then you should adopt JWE based approach. You can read more about this in [RFC7516](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516). For encryption, you can use either symmetric or asymmetric keys. Once you receive JWE based JWT, you can validate that it was sent by intended party by successful decryption of the JWT payload.